# What is the sed comand to fix this file so last value on each line is double quoted

Tags: sed, text-processing, regex

I have a file containing two million lines of the form:

```
"00005cea-668e-4475-9e19-92a25c8b74fb",129.24728",D#
```

the last value should actually be:

```
"00005cea-668e-4475-9e19-92a25c8b74fb",129.24728,"D#"
```

Please , how do I use sed command to fix this file so the spurious " is removed and the last value is double quoted

Comment: Is this `129.24728"` correct or a typo?

Comment: @A.B. it's to be removed.

Comment: Instead of deleting why don't double quote all like: `"00005cea-668e-4475-9e19-92a25c8b74fb","129.24728","D#"`

Comment: @snoop because its a numeric value, its a csv file to be imported into a db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
sed -r 's/",([^,]*)$/,"\1"/' input-file
```

That's  a `",` followed by anything that's not a comma (`[^,]`) till the end of the file `$`. `\1` is the part matched by in the parentheses - `([^,]*)`.

Comment: Great this looked the simplest solution and worked flawlessly

Answer (score 3):

Not `sed`, but `perl`:

```
perl -F, -ane '($f1)=$F[1]=~/(.*)"/; $F[2]=~s/\n//g; print "$F[0],$f1,\"$F[2]\"\n";'
```

Explanation:

- `perl -F, -ane` reads the input line-wise and splits the line on a `,`
- `($f1)=$F[1]=~/(.*)"/;` removes the `"` in the second column
- `$F[2]=~s/\n//g;` removes the newline at the end
- `print "$F[0],$f1,\"$F[2]\"\n";` writes the output and adds the `"` to the last value

---

Edit - shortened Version (thanks to @kos):

```
perl -F, -lane '$F[1]=~s/"$//; print "$F[0],$F[1],\"$F[2]\"";'
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your fields are defined by commas. If so, you can do this in `sed`:

```
sed -i -r 's/",([^,]*)$/,"\1"/' file
```

Or, in Perl:

```
perl  -i -lpe 's/",([^,]*)$/,"\1"/' file
```

In both cases, the regex simply looks for a comma, then 0 or more non-commas until the end of the line. The parentheses capture the last fields which we can then refer to as `\1` (or `$1` in perl). This is then replaced by itself inside double quotes. The `-i` is for editing the file in place, changes are made to the original file.

You could also use `awk`:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{sub(/"/,"",$(NF-1)); $NF="\""$NF"\""}1;' file
```

Or, if your version supports it:

```
awk -iinplace -F, -vOFS=, '{sub(/"/,"",$(NF-1)); $NF="\""$NF"\""}1;' file
```

Comment: OP wants to eliminate the `"` at the end of the second field.

Comment: @muru thanks, I'd missed that. I'd also missed seeing your answer before posting mine. Added something more to differentiate.